# Read data frame until a specific row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is divided into 2 parts.  Here's an example:

| Type A |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| **Type B** |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

`Type A` and `Type B` are headers that appear before the data.  How can I tell R to read all the rows before the row where `Type B` appears?

Comment: Depending on the input format (e.g. xlsx or csv or whatever) reading functions usually have a parameter where you can specify how many rows you want to read in: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table This of course requires you to know in advance in which row the second header starts.

Comment: Is this a text file?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention- it's an excel file. The problem is each time the file has different amount of rows. The only parameter I have is the header name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `which` here:

```r
df[1:(which(df$col1 == "Type B") - 1), ]
```

This assumes that you in fact have just a single data frame, and that the first column is named `col1` (change above snippet as appropriate).

Comment: This worked perfect! Just a question- what is the meaning of the - 1 part?

Comment: @adiki The call to `which(...)` will return the row index of the row matching `Type B`.  As you want to read everything up to, but _excluding_, this row, we subtract one from this value.

Comment: Will it exclude just the row where Type B appears or all rows from Type B and below it?

Comment: The latter; it will include all rows up to, but not including, the "Type B" row.  If "Type B" could occur more than once, then you need to reveal which occurrence is the breaking point.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `read.table` with `skip = 1` to skip the first line (`"Type A"`) and drop the rows after you find `'Type'` in the 1st column.

```
tmp <- read.table('file.txt', skip = 1, fill = TRUE)
result <- tmp[seq_len(grep('Type', tmp$V1) - 1), ]
result <- type.convert(result, as.is = TRUE)
result
```